# Como criar um ID para ser usado em outras classes

Tags: java, android

Meu aplicativo vai fazer um get na primeira tela do ID do usuário, como faço para usá-lo em outras `activities` sem ser via `intent` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode armazenar em um Shared Preferences, embora eu não tenha certeza que é a melhor opção:

```
// Inicializar
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("shared_pref_key", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

// Save Data
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
editor.putInt("id", 1);
editor.commit();

//Pegar valor
int myIntValue = sharedPreferences.getInt("your_int_key", -1);
```

Answer (score 1):

Cria uma classe pra setar e pegar o valor:

```
public class User extends Application {

private String Id;

public String getId()
{
    return Id;
}
public void setId(String Id)
{
    this.Id = Id;
}
```

}

E seta o id quando vc pegar ele pela primeira vez.

```
                User usuario = ((User)getApplicationContext());
            usuario.setId(id);//variável com o id
```

Pra recuperar(no exemplo, exibe a variável setada em um snackbar):

```
        User usuario = ((User)getApplicationContext());
        Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar
                .make(principal, "Bem Vindo, " + usuario.getId(), Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
        snackbar.show();
```